# Confusion about android:installLocation permissions

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Just looking through the permissions for my app, and I was wondering if I need the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in my Manifest when using `android:installLocation="auto"`.

I have had a look at the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) which do not mention anything about permissions, but [other documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) states that I do need the permission to read from external storage:

> In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` system permissions.

Also, the [documentation about the permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) states:

> Allows an application to read from external storage.
>
> Any app that declares the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is implicitly granted this permission.
>
> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.
>
> Also starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String)` and `getExternalCacheDir()`.

Therefore I am not sure whether or not I do need the permission for the `installLocation` attribute in the Manifest file, as it means my app will read from external storage, but as I said before, the documentation specifically on App Install Location doesn't mention permissions.

Do I need the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the permission.

Before Android 6.0, `android:installLocation` would not affect your app's internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`). It would only affect where your APK is located. Hence, the permission does not apply.

Android 6.0 now allows users to dedicate removable storage (e.g., a micro SD card) as a place for installing apps. In this case, your internal storage happens to be on an encrypted partition put on the removable storage. However, this is still not external storage, and so the permission does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy and detailed response. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me, and I did not know about the new Android 6.0 feature you explained in the last paragraph.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh: You can learn more about the "adoptable" removable storage in [the 6.0 preview documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-adoptable-storage). Right now, it is not that useful, as no Nexus device offers a micro SD card, and having a USB OTG thumb drive hanging off your phone or tablet is a bit awkward... :-)